# Redux-toolkit async thunk unwrap method error using Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I trying to use `unwrap` method in order to get access `then` but I getting following error. How to get rid of this? I didn't found anything in docs.

`Property 'unwrap' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, RegisterCredentials, {}>'`

```
        dispatch(register({
            email: formik.values.email,
            password: formik.values.password,
            comfirmPassword: formik.values.comfirmPassword
        })).unwrap().then(() => {
            navigate('/browse')
        })
```

`createAsyncThunk` function:

```
type RegisterCredentials = {
    email: string,
    password: string,
    comfirmPassword: string
}

export const register = createAsyncThunk<any, RegisterCredentials>('user/register', async ({ email, password }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
})
```

Comment: I already solved issue :) https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type